# Flutter web scrollview with mouse outside of listview

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a GridView that I want to make scrollable even when the mouse is outside of the GridView. I have tried to add the GridView inside a SingleChildScrollView and added shrinkWrap: true to the GridView. I have also tried adding a Column around the GridView and Expanded as well. Here is the code:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 750),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                    itemCount: course.subjects.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
                      return CourseSubjectListEl(course, idx, data);
                    },
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, you can only scroll when the mouse is over the GridView. I think this problem can cause confusion for web users, where you normally can scroll with the mouse everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```dart
primary: false,
```

Property inside `GridView`. That will make the GridView scroll physics false and will act on how the parent scrolls (which in case is your `SingleChildScrollView`).

Probably you might want to remove `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` and add the above property.

Note: Make sure your scrollview contains the whole width of the screen you want to scroll

Comment: How do I make sure the scrollview contains the whole width of the screen? Only the primary: false field does not work.

Comment: I simply used a wrapped the element in a Row. Is it a better way of doing it?

Comment: I am not sure of the `Row`. The `SingleChildScrollView` to be contained the whole width can be made by making its parent contain the width probably a `SizedBox` or any other widget. `SingleChildScrollView` takes size of it's parent to contain within.